# How to find the IP addresses of different nodes on a HDInsight cluster

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-cli, azureportal

I have a HDInsight cluster running Storm. This cluster was set up (not by me) without DNS, so it can only be accessed by using the IP address in the URL. How to find the IP address for the head node? I have accessed it before, but the IP address was given to me by someone. In future we will create additional clusters like this and I want to know the general method for finding the head node IP address

Ideally using CLI or the portal

EDIT: The HDInsight cluster is already in a VNET.

Here is a more succinct version of my question. How do I find the IP address without using the cluster name?

Comment: You could get it via ​[Ambari ​RE​ST ​AP​I](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-manage-ambari-rest-api#example-get-the-internal-ip-address-of-cluster-nodes).

Comment: @Joy Wang Don't I need to use the cluster name to do that? That won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is that you can find the IP addresses if you navigate to the Overview of the Virtual Network resource.

Answer (score 1):

ssh into your cluster's head node and run `$curl ifconfig.me` command to get the IP address of head nodes.

You can get fully qualified domain names (FQDN) of all nodes on the cluster using below bash command (Replace $CLUSTERNAME with your cluster name).

```
curl -u admin -sS -G "https://$CLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTERNAME/hosts" \
| jq '.items[].Hosts.host_name'
```

It may ask you to install "jq". The above command will return the list of nodes as below

```
"hn0-mydemo.lle2qymtat0ehndwwaba2j1gih.dx.internal.cloudapp.net"
"hn1-mydemo.lle2qymtat0ehndwwaba2j1gih.dx.internal.cloudapp.net"
"wn0-mydemo.lle2qymtat0ehndwwaba2j1gih.dx.internal.cloudapp.net"
"wn1-mydemo.lle2qymtat0ehndwwaba2j1gih.dx.internal.cloudapp.net"
"wn2-mydemo.lle2qymtat0ehndwwaba2j1gih.dx.internal.cloudapp.net"
"wn3-mydemo.lle2qymtat0ehndwwaba2j1gih.dx.internal.cloudapp.net"
"zk0-mydemo.lle2qymtat0ehndwwaba2j1gih.dx.internal.cloudapp.net"
"zk2-mydemo.lle2qymtat0ehndwwaba2j1gih.dx.internal.cloudapp.net"
"zk3-mydemo.lle2qymtat0ehndwwaba2j1gih.dx.internal.cloudapp.net"
```

You can SSH into your worker nodes from within your headnode SSH session using below command

```
ssh sshuser@wn0-mydemo
```

once you SSH into worker node run `$curl ifconfig.me` command to get the IP address of worker nodes

Usually, both the head nodes have same IP address and all the 4 worker nodes have same IP address.

Answer (score -1):

Azure HDInsight cluster [uses Secure Shell (SSH) to securely connect to Hadoop on Azure HDInsight Storm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/storm/apache-storm-tutorial-get-started-linux#run-a-storm-starter-sample-on-hdinsight).

For more details,  refer "[Connect to HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-linux-use-ssh-unix)".

**Note:** Azure HDInsight cluster will not allow any public IP to be assigned to it.

If you need a IP to be allocated to HDInsight cluster, you would have to create HDInsight in a VNET.

For more details, refer “[Extend Azure HDInsight using an Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-extend-hadoop-virtual-network#hdinsight-ip)”.

Comment: I will update the question, but the cluster is in a VNET. Also, the question isn't asking 'how' to connect. I know that already. I just want to 'find' the IP address